# Resource recommendations for reading Nietzsche (especially his "the joyous science")

Tags: reference-request

As the title says, I wish to know about certain resources that explain the ideology of nietzsche, especially a sort of "paragraph to paragraph" explanation (since I feel somewhat lost in what Nietzsche might be trying to explain something or where he's getting at)